# having issues with where strtok is cutting off

Tags: c, strtok

Basically for my code I have variable/key pairs. When a variable is encountered in the code, a function (which contains part of the lines below), it is replaced with its key. Example, if the user input the string "Hello ABC World" and a variable was declared as ABC = "Great Big", the input string would be altered to "Hellow Great Big World". I accomplish this by strtok'ing the part of the string before the variable and after the variable, then concatenizing newfirst (the part before the variable) + the variable key + newsecond (the part after the variable). For the most part, this works well, EXCEPT when the variable is at the end of the string "Hello World ABC". therefore leaving what i believe is the single character '\n', and throwing an error because it can not tokenize what is left. Is there any way I can error handle my way around this?

```
           // Place the part of the string before the variable prescence in newfirst
            strcpy(newfirst, strtok(nonVariable[i], myVariables[a].variable));

            // Place the part of the string after the variable prescence in newsecond
            for(c = 0; c < strlen(newsecond); c++)
            {
                if(newsecond[c] == ' ')
                    hasSpaces = 1;
            }
            if(hasSpaces = 0)
            {
                strcpy(newsecond, strtok(NULL, "\n"));
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(newsecond, strtok(NULL, " "));
                strcpy(newsecond, strtok(NULL, "\n"));
            }

            // substitute all key values in for their corresponding variables
            strcat(newfirst, " ");
            strcat(newfirst, myVariables[a].key);
            strcat(newfirst, " ");
            strcat(newfirst, newsecond); 
            strcpy(nonVariable[i], newfirst);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a delimiter string with several chars to `strtok()`:

```
ptr = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
```

See [man strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)